# What's a recursive way to move the second element of a list to the front? [Racket]

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I recursively move the middle of a 3-element list to the front of the list? There are nested lists.

So,

```
 ((not #f) iff (((#f implies #t) and #t) or #f))
```

Should become

```
(iff (not #f) (or (and (implies #f #t) #t) #f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really good use of [`match`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) because we can set a condition for the 3-element list and simply ignore the other cases -

```
(define (transform l)
  (match l
    ((list a b c)
     (list (transform b)
           (transform a)
           (transform c)))
    (_
     l)))

(transform '((not #f) iff (((#f implies #t) and #t) or #f)))
; '(iff (not #f) (or (and (implies #f #t) #t) #f))
```

@PetSerAl catches a bug in the comments. Here's the fix -

```
(define (transform l)
  (match l
    ((list a b c)             ; a 3-element list
     (list (transform b)
           (transform a)
           (transform c)))
    ((? list? _)              ; any other list
      (map transform l))
    (_                        ; a non-list
     l)))

(transform '(not (#f implies #t)))
; '(not (implies #f #t)
```

Comment: How about `'(not (#f implies #t))` as input?

Comment: Nice catch, @PetSerAl. I think the edit takes care of it :D

Comment: It depends what OP want out of `(transform '(a b c d))`: `'(a c b d)` or `'(a b c d)`. If OP what second, then `((? list? _) (map transform  l))` should do the job.

Comment: I like that even better as the transform _only_ targets 3-element lists now. Thanks for the comments.