# Evaluating a list of booleans?

Tags: scheme, racket

I've got a list that I want to evaluate the truth of, but (unless I'm missing some built-in aspect of Racket/Scheme) I need to convert it to a Boolean to do that.

For example, I have

```
'(#t and #f)
```

I need

```
(function '(#t and #f)) ;in order to return...
>#f
```

I've tried `(eval '(and #t #f)` but get this error message:

```
  and: unbound identifier;
  also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: and
```

I have code in place that converts '(#t and #f) into '(and #t #f) so that shouldn't be an issue, as far as I'm aware.

```
(define (Evaluate-WFF lst)
  (match lst
    ((list a b c)
     (list (reorg b)
       (reorg a)
       (reorg c)))
    (_ lst)))
```

When I try to `eval` from this, I get the error message stated earlier.

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing `'(and #t #f)`at all?  Please post a [mcve], not bits and pieces of code.

Comment: Please stop writing `[Racket]` in the title of your questions, it's unnecessary because you already tagged the question as `racket`.

Comment: make sure to avoid the bug in `Evaluate-WFF`. See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55193921/633183) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what language you're using you might need to provide a namespace, as per the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html). In `#lang racket` this is how to do it:

```
(define-namespace-anchor a)
(define ns (namespace-anchor->namespace a))

(eval '(and #t #f) ns)
=> #f
```